# How can I use url_for in jinja?

Tags: python, flask

I have a issue during using `url_for`  in `jinja template`. I use like :

```
href="{{ url_for('user',user_id=current_user.id)}}"
```

when I write `href="user/{{current_user.id}}`" it works perfectly ::

and my view function is :

```
@app.route('/user/<user_id>')
def get_user(user_id):
    user = Users.query.filter_by(id = user_id).first()
    return render_template("profile.html", user = user)
```

but my jinja cant see this url and has an errors

```
werkzeug.routing.exceptions.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'user' with values ['user_id']. Did you mean 'get_user' instead
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message suggested, you have to provide the name of the view function to [`url_for()`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/quickstart/#url-building):

```
href="{{ url_for('get_user', user_id=current_user.id)}}"
```

Comment: thancks a lot <3